# Cancelling all operations on OperationQueue

Tags: swift, nsoperationqueue

When cancelling all operations in the queue, as the docs says, some operations could be still left in the queue, which is fine. But let's say that from 5 operations in queue with `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1`. This second operation is failing and then I call `cancelAllOperations()`. When I check the queue there is still one operation inside. In the app then I pull to refresh i want to repeat the process, but what about the previous operation left? I want to reuse the same queue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well even setting `isExecuting = false` and `isFinished = true` the operations were still in the queue. What I did was re-initializing the queue again after cancelling the requests. In that way the operations are "deleted" and the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling isn't the thing that removes operations from a queue. The thing that triggers their removal is setting the operation's `finished` to `true`. Once the queue sees the `finished` moving to `true` it removes the operation from the queue. If an operation is still in the queue, maybe its `finished` wasn't set properly.